# утерян пароль от mysql

Tags: mysql, password-hash

Есть самописное ПО, цепляется к базе mysql5. Пароль от mysql безвозвратно забыт всеми. Подскажите, можно ли его как либо восстановить без перезаписи, кроме как перебором? Пароль не словарный, перебирать дюже долго...

upd: пароль прописан в exe файле программы

UPD2: Пароль, снятый снифером выглядит 0d:83:94:d8:ad:4f:b4:de:0a:8e:f3:c2:19:ec:e6:20:b9:f1:9c:ba вот так. Пароль из программы не тянется. aes_encrypt(password, 'mysql') видимо тоже не прокатит :( Есть еще варианты? или как разобрать пароль из хеша выше?

Comment: "*пароль прописан в exe файле софтины*" - ну так и поищите его в секциях данных. Если он не зашифрован там, конечно.

Comment: он там не зашифрован, вопрос опять таки, какими средствами копать? winhex не нашли.

Comment: wireshark и смотреть, что она передает.

Comment: Пароль передается в открытом виде? Не думаю, это было бы большой угрозой для безопасности.

Comment: Да, пароль должен передаваться в открытом виде, в тз не было шифровать пароль.

Answer (score 1):

Пароль отлично ищется по экзешнику из Far Manager. Что в релизе, что в дебаге. Примерно в том же блоке, где лежит имя MySQL сервера.

Еще по идее можно переконвертировать программу в текстовый asm файл, правда не помню чем это можно сделать.

Попробовал решить задачу через WinDbg:

File->Open Executable - указываем экзешник.

Пишем в консоли WinDbg:

bp main - устанавливаем точку остановки на функцию main.

g - запускаем выполнение программы, она грузит библиотеки и практически сразу останавливается на main.

bp mysql_real_connect - устанавливаем точку остановки на mysql_real_connect. Производим действия с программой, которые приведут к подключению к БД.

WinDbg должен остановиться с сообщением: libmysql!mysql_real_connect:

pt - пройти до конца функции.

p - сделать шаг для выхода из функции.

Меню View->Locals, у меня там отображаются все переменные и значения. Но боюсь это только по тому, что есть отладочная информация. Как получить значения без нее пока не понимаю.

Comment: прога написана не на C :( С Far Manager попробую сейчас что нибудь накопать.

Comment: А на чем? Я сразу же проверил, ищется ли пароль в бинарнике. Есть исходники проекта? Собери бинарник и проверь.

Comment: были бы исходники, не было бы проблем :( исходников нет. написано на чем то вроде С++, не помню как называется язык. Через фар тоже ничего.

Comment: Это уже тянет на полноценный взлом. Короче, WinDbg в зубы и вперед.

Comment: Подскажите ошибка 0n5 отказано в доступе через WinDbg. Гугление не помогло решить проблему, либо плохо гуглил